# Obtaining output of a C program in python

Tags: python, c, subprocess, popen

Kind of a simple question but I can't find anything near my issue so here I go, I'm trying to execute a C program in Python to get the output, problem is it doesn't work. 
I've got no error but when I try to print the output I just get nothing, like a blank space or something, but if I print what is being outputed (is that a word?) in my C it works just fine, so here's my python code:

```
command = "./serialize %s %s %s" %(binary , width , height)
p=subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
print output
```

(pretty straight forward, binary is a string and width and height are integers)

And if you want to know, here's my C code :

```
char* main(char* argc,char* argv[]){
char* r;
r = serialize(argv[1],atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3]));
printf("%s", r);
return r;
}
```

(serialize is a function I made that works perfectly fine, I know because of the printf just before the return that give me what I want).

So if you have any idea that'd be great, thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Two issues here:

- `Popen` takes a *list* of arguments, not a string. Passing that when `shell=True` is a bad security hazard. Imagine if `width` equaled `; rm -rf /`.
- The return value is a special object that contains information about the *running* process. `Popen` doesn't wait for the process to return.

Try:

```
command = ['./serialize', binary, str(width), str(height)]
stdout, stderr = subprocess.check_output(command)
print stdout, stderr
```

If you want both stdout and stderr in one string, do:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Your C code is also incorrect. `main` should return an `int` with the process return code (0 in this case), and you can use `puts(r)` instead of `printf`. It will also violently crash if you pass fewer than 3 arguments. In addition, `argc` is also an `int`. Try something like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* r;
    if (argc < 4) {
        puts("Too few arguments");
        return 1;
    }
    r = serialize(argv[1],atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3]));
    puts(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that but I got an error, here the traceback:

                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testsql.py", line 77, in <module>
    stdout, stderr = subprocess.check_output(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 567, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1340, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Comment: @DrunkenChoko Are `width` and `height` integers? I believe so; I updated the answer.

Comment: Argh, well, new day, new error, returned non-zero exit status 32, it's pretty ugly I would said.

Comment: @DrunkenChoko You need to also apply the changes to your C file I mentioned.

Comment: Had an error "to many value to unpack", to supress it I replace the tuple like this: 
      output=subprocess.check_output(command,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print output

but now I get nothing like in the beginning

Comment: @DrunkenChoko Hmmm...how are you running your Python script?

Comment: well      python programm.py